# Calling a customFields paint method

Tags: blackberry, java-me, paint, custom-fields

I am working on an application that displays a chart on screen.  I made a custom field whose paint function renders the chart. Now I want to know how I can call this function so that my chart is shown. I have attatched a sample code here but all I see is a blank white screen.

```
public class Graph extends MainScreen
{
       class MyField extends Field
       {
            protected void layout(int w,int h)
            {
                  setExtent(getWidth(),getHeight());
            }

            protected void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                    //my graph is drawn here
            }

            public MyField()
            {
                 paint(getGraphics());
            }
      }

      public Graph()
      {
          VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();
          vfm.add(new MyField());
          add(vfm);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I notice is that your `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` calls are being used to set the extent. Until you've actually finished calling `setExtent()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` will return 0. You should be doing your own calculations to determine how wide and tall your Field is, and then set that for the extent (as long as they are less than the max width and max height being passed to `layout()`. Also, it isn't necessary to call `paint()` from the constructor, as the Manager it is in will make that call for you when it needs to be painted.